# Change cursor color on web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to change the color of the mouse pointer, so it matches the theme of your web site?

Comment: I personally do not recommend this. The cursor is one fundamental thing of the operating system that the user probably does not want to have changed.

Comment: Let's bring back Comet Cursor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the color. You can create your own cursor image though, and apply it in css with the [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/cursor) property:

```
body {
    cursor: url(myCursor.cur);
}
```

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property) is relevant.

Comment: I think Firefox (maybe others) insist on a "real" cursor keyword to follow the URL (like "auto" or "pointer").

Answer (score 1):

The "cursor" CSS property can be given the URL of an image to use:

```
.foo { cursor: url(whatever/cursor.cur) auto;
```

Different browsers have differing support for this; Opera has none I think.